# Jquery, 'is not a function', extension-function not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, spinner

I get this error in the console of Firefox:

```
$spinner.setupSpinner is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$spinner.setupSpinner();
```

ed247.base.js (line 116)

Postliste.aspx loads these files:

```
jquery-1.9.0.js"
jquery-ui-1.9.0.js
jquery.ui.datepicker-no.js
jquery-scrollTo-min.js
ed247.base.js
```

Excerpt of ed247.base.js :

```
    jQuery.fn.setupSpinner = function () {
        $(this)
            .ajaxStart(function () {
                $(this).show();
            })
            .ajaxStop(function () {
                $(this).hide();
            })
        ;
        return this;
    };

    // init
    function init() {
        // cache jquery objects
        $item = $(config.ids.item);
        $searchResult = $(config.ids.searchResult);
        $spinner = $(config.ids.spinner);
        $datepicker = $(config.ids.datepicker);
        $todatepicker = $(config.ids.todatepicker);
        $searchButton = $(config.ids.searchButton);
        $searchItemTemplate = $(config.templateids.searchItemTemplate);
        $searchHeaderTemplate = $(config.templateids.searchHeaderTemplate);
        $itemTemplate = $(config.templateids.itemTemplate);
        $attachmentsTemplate = $(config.templateids.attachmentsTemplate);
        $backLinks = $(config.classes.backLinks);
        $checkout = $(config.ids.checkout);


        $backToStep1 = $backLinks.find("li:nth-child(1)");
        $backToStep2 = $backLinks.find("li:nth-child(2)");

        $spinner.setupSpinner();
```

Here is the URL to the page: [Link](http://www.roros.kommune.no/Politikk/Postliste/Journalpost-info1/)

The problem seems to be that the extension function isn't found?
How do I solve this?

Comment: How to reproduce this error? Looking on your website with firebug doesn't throw an error.

Comment: And where do you set `$spinner`? Is it a jQuery object for sure?

Comment: @Simon,
http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/

Comment: @Simon,
To reproduce the error:
Go to the website.
Press the F5-key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the jQuery library twice. When you try to use the extension, it's not there any more, because you have replaced the jQuery object with a new one.

Comment: Indeed he's loading the jQuery library twice, I didn't see that one. But one question: he's loading his script after the two includes of jQuery. Shouldn't it be without consequences? As the first jQuey object gets overridden with the second one and he's then extending the second jQuery object?

Comment: @Simon: No, the script with the extension is loaded after the first include of jQuery. The second include of jQuery is in the body, so it loads after the extension is added, but before the `ready` event where the extension is used.

Comment: @Guffa,
Thanks for your reply!
I removed the extra reference. I have gone through all the files that should be loaded, but I can't find where JQuery is loaded.
Right now the JQuery-files are loading after the script with the spinner-function, so I get a JQuery-error because of that JQuery hasn't been loaded.
Any tip of a good work-around?

Comment: @AndersBranderud: You removed the first jQuery include instead of the second, so now jQuery isn't loaded yet when you try to add the extension.

Comment: @Guffa,
Yes, I know.
The problem is that I haven't written all of the code and I can't find the second JQuery-include, despite looking through the aspx-pages and Masterpage that is loading.

Thus I wonder if there is any work-around. I will put back the first JQuery-include.

Comment: @AndersBranderud: If you can't get rid of the second include, you may be able to solve it by rearranging your code to use that one instead, or use the `noConflict` method to use the two versions without one overwriting the other.

Comment: @Guffa,
Thanks. I am now using noConflict.
It seems like am getting another conflict at this function call
'$backToStep1.localScroll' ..
It is resulting in function not defined-error.
However I know that the code is working when only one JQuery-reference is used.

My JQuery-variable is $jquery190. How can I define that this should be used?

Comment: @AndersBranderud: You can put your code inside a function expression that you call with your instance, that way the code inside the function uses that instance: `(function($){ ... }(@jquery190));`.